# Does the result given below work for composite numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

So, in the example given below, author states for prime numbers. But in the proving part, we don't have any condition for p being prime. Now later on, this same result can be used for proving *Fermat's little theorem*. Now Fermat's theorem works for prime numbers (sometimes for composite also - *Carmichael or non-charmichael*). In this result why is author being specific for primes? It does work for composites also. So.is there any condition am I missing?
Please check the image.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyuj4.jpg)

Comment: Euler-Fermat theorem and the totient function can help generalize this result.

Comment: My problem isn't about generalizing the result. This small result can be used for proving a bigger theorem, and in the way, we don't have any condition for p being prime, so does this imply Fermat's theorem works for composite? No. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: Ok thanks. I got it. Euclid's lemma is for *relativity prime numbers*. Here p and r! are of course, relativity prime, hence the result.

Comment: The hinted inductive proof of little Fermat *does* use that $p$ is prime - see the linked dupe.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a comment earlier but it seemed to have given you an incorrect idea of what I meant. Here is what I meant in detail:

Since, $$\binom{n}{r}\cdot r! = (n-r+1)\cdot (n-r+2)\cdots n$$

If $n$ is a prime, it readily follows that $n$ does not divide $r!$ and hence $n | \binom{n}{r}$.

Similarly you can argue if $n$ and $r!$ are coprime, then $n | \binom{n}{r}$, however this can be improved further.

If $n$ is a composite, you can write it as a product of primes each less than $n$ itself. Suppose $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdot p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$.

Then for $n | \binom{n}{r}$, you will need to take into account $p$-adic valuations. Find the highest power of each prime factor of $n$ that divides $n!$, $(n-r)!$ and $r!$. I denote them by $v_{p_k}(n!)$, $v_{p_k}(n-r)!$, and $v_{p_k}(r!)$. If $v_{p_k}(n!)-v_{p_k}(r!) - v_{p_k}(n-r)! \geq a_k$, then ${p_k}^{a_k}$ divides $\binom{n}{r}$. You will have to find this for all $p$ which are factors of $n$.

As a special case, whenever $n$ and $r$ are co-prime, it must be true that $n | \binom{n}{r}$. You can find various proofs online. But this is not an exhaustive criterion.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for the response. I understood. Actually I'm new to number theory and self learning for INMO, so I don't have much knowledge of general functions, in fact I learned Euler's theorem today only !